# How can I lower the volume of the sounds of mastery emotes and level ups?

Tags: league-of-legends

How can I lower the volume of the sounds of mastery emotes and level ups? At the same time I don't want to change the volume of spell effects and other meaningful sounds. So far, I've tried all the options in the sound settings. Do I really have to lower the master volume and up everything under it?

Comment: Is't there a slider just for SFX? I can't check right now but I'm pretty sure there is

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to manage the sounds on a level that isn't designed on the client side.  I'm not familiar enough with the LoL interface to provide a good quality answer; but in many games there are not specific volume options for those settings.  You _may_ be able to play around with config files or something similar; but I get the feeling that capability was never designed into the game in any capacity.  Such adjustments may involve the developers manually adjusting the volume of the sound files (which may be another alternative to look into depending on how obscured they are).

Comment: I tried the SFX slider but that doesnt affect these 2 sounds, and where can i find such config files and will they be changed with patches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option to lower those two sound effects specifically. I suspect those belong in the "Sound Effects" category, so the only way to lower those volumes is to also lower the sound effect volume, which you can do in-game by opening the menu and looking the audio options.

You do have another option for the mastery emotes though. If there is a player who is spamming their emote and you find it annoying, you can mute that player by typing `ignore PlayerName` or by clicking the mute button next to their champion portrait on the stats window. This will prevent you from seeing/hearing their mastery emote, as well as their other emotes as well (dance, laugh, taunt, etc). The downside is that you will unable to see anything they type in chat... but then again, if they're spamming their emotes they probably don't have anything too useful to say anyways.

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflegends/comments/5htvy9/you_can_actually_mute_emotes_of_a_player)

Comment: I believe as that as of this (or the previous) patch it's possible to mute text and mute sounds separately

Comment: SFX volume doesnt affect these 2 sounds. I tried that in a sandbox game. Neither does any other slider, except master volume.